# How to replace "&amp;" within CDATA in XML to interpret in Java Script (ECMAScript for XML)

Tags: javascript, xml, replace, cdata

```
var newstring = srchStr3.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");


var srchStr3 = job.getJobInfo("JobData").replace("&amp;", "&");
```

These are some snipnets I tried which could not fix the issue

Comment: I need a Javascript code not XML

Comment: What is your expect output for the `str = "&amp;"` input exactly ? "&" ? Also, your snippet references some variables that are not shown. You may need to clarify that a bit.

Comment: Also, what is JavaScript 2.2 ? The current "official" version of JavaScript is EcmaScript 5 . "JavaScript 2.2" sounds like you are trying to develop a site for some outdated technology like Netscape Navigator.

Comment: This is for a different software called Lasernet. This software follows older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have some JavaScript code embedded in XML that is inappropriately escaped. *(If that is not the case please edit your question.)*

You wouldn't need to have to do this in JS (nor do I think it's actually feasible) if your JS code was within CDATA, e.g.:

```
<code>
  <![CDATA[
    function foo(a, b) {
      return a && b;
    }
  ]]>
</code>
```

When you process the XML make sure the output is text.
With XSL for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/code">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces this output:

```
$ xsltproc ~/Desktop/so.xsl ~/Desktop/so.xml 


    function foo(a, b) {
      return a && b;
    }
```